# What is the current status of the convergence of the post-Newtonian approximation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, perturbation-theory, post-newtonian

In the very well written article by C. Will, [On the Unreasonable Effectiveness of the post-Newtonian Approximation in Gravitational Physics](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1103127108), he states:

> The one question that remains open is the nature of the post-Newtonian sequence; we still do not know if it converges, diverges or is asymptotic. Despite this, it has proven to be remarkably effective.

What is the current status of the convergence of the post-Newtonian sequence? Are there indications that it is possibly asymptotic?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377 is an article from 2014, a few years after the other one.

Comment: @JohnHunter That paper is about the experimental confrontation with GR theory. It's a good paper, but doesn't address what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3):

The question about PN sequence is raiser mathematical one, nor physical or philosophical. It has a good answer in the paper "Newtonian and post-Newtonian approximations are asymptotic to general relativity" by T. Futamase and Bernard,  F. Schutz, Phys. Rev. D 28, 2363 – Published 15 November 1983. The Abstract to this paper is clearly stated that the PN approximations "are genuine asymptotic approximations to general relativity". Also this question discussed in many papers such as
Blanchet, L., “Gravitational Radiation from Post-Newtonian Sources and Inspiralling Compact Binaries”, Living Rev. Relativity, 9, lrr-2006-4, (2006). URL (cited on 3 August 2006): http://www.livingreviews.org/lrr-2006-4. 2.2, 3

"The Post-Newtonian Approximation for Relativistic Compact Binaries", by Toshifumi Futamase&Yousuke Itoh, Living Reviews in Relativity, 12 Mar 2007, 10(1):2

"Accuracy of the post-Newtonian approximation: Optimal asymptotic expansion for quasicircular, extreme-mass ratio inspirals" by Nicolás Yunes and Emanuele Berti, Phys. Rev. D 77, 124006 – Published 5 June 2008; Erratum Phys. Rev. D 83, 109901 (2011).

Comment: Thanks for the references. Now I'm wondering why Will would say in 2011 that the issue is still unsolved if a paper in 1983 claimed to solve it?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin: Futamase & Schutz prove their result under assumptions of small velocities and near flatness, this is the domain of “reasonable effectiveness” of PN approximation. Will talks about how “unreasonably” well PN approximation works in strong gravity situations such as late stage inspirals.

Comment: @A.V.S. you've completely misunderstood my question. The title of Will's paper is a reference to the similarly named paper by Eugene Wigner, and is inconsequential to my question here. I quoted the sentence from Will's paper where he says that the only remaining unsolved problem with post-Newtonian physics is the question of its convergence. So I'm wondering why did Will say this even though the paper by Futamase and Schutz claims to have answered that question?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin: I am aware of Wigner paper and hoped that you would understand my meaning: the result of Futamase and Schutz is inapplicable to the kind of situations C.Will is talking about.

Comment: @A.V.S. That makes no sense. How could the situation that Will is talking about, i.e. whether the PN approximation is convergent, divergent, or asymptotic, be inapplicable to the result of the Futamase and Schutz paper, which is to prove that the PN approximation (which is valid in the limit of slow speeds and weak gravity) is asymptotic? They seem to be about the same exact thing. Notice that Will did not say that "the only unsolved problem is whether the PN approx. is convergent in the strong gravity regime." Rather, he said the problem is unsolved in the PN regime...

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin: To see that Futamase & Schutz is inapplicable to a lot of reasonable situations, consider the *early* stage inspiral of two black holes, when BHs orbiting each other slowly. The situation is well described by several first PN terms of two-body problem  (see e.g. [this review](https://doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2014-2) for equations), but because there is no almost flat Cauchy data F&Sch is inapplicable.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin I think that Clifford M. Will and other doing a nice job to extend PN approximations to what they called as post-Newtonian theory. From the other hand  Futamase & Schutz  also did a nice job to prove that PN approximations are in fact asymptotic approximations to the sequence of fully relativistic solutions.  It is not clear  why Clifford M. Will does not mentioned  Futamase & Schutz in his review.

Comment: @A.V.S. I don't understand your comments. Could you post your thinking about Futamase & Schutz paper with some explanation?

Comment: @AlexTrounev: I thought that “is inapplicable” was pretty clear. Note, that authors themselves do not claim that their result is applicable to things like Hulse–Taylor binary (though PN approximation by itself works quite well there).

Comment: @A.V.S. Please, see update to my answer with reference to paper by  Toshifumi Futamase&Yousuke Itoh on https://europepmc.org/article/MED/28179819

Comment: @AlexTrounev: F & I 2007 is a great review, but it is about physics, it does not answer OP's mathematical question (your words!) and only provides “strong evidence” and not proofs in support. Ultimately this state of affairs is why C. Will calls the problem open.

Comment: @A.V.S. Section 2 Foundation of the Post-Newtonian Approximation of the paper The Post-Newtonian Approximation for Relativistic Compact Binaries by Futamase&Itoh consists of the nice explanation the problem discussed above.  They follow to previous paper by Futamase & Schutz. Also they mentioned that "Blanchet and Damour have developed a systematic approach of a matched asymptotic expansion" and that "In fact, both the Blanchet–Damour method and the Will–Wiseman method are proved to give
a physically equivalent result".

Comment: @A.V.S. Well, I specifically asked why the Futamasi and Shutz paper "is inapplicable" but you kind of just keep stating that it is... I would very much appreciate a more careful explanation, as this is beyond my expertise. Can you perhaps make a precise statement about what regime precisely their result is applicable in?... like, does the F&Sch result require flat Cauchy data? Or asymptotically flat Cauchy data? These are the exact details I'm wondering about and it is not clear to me.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin: The F&Sch result is applicable in situations with vanishing self-gravity, i.e. it could not be applied to things like neutron stars and black holes. Note that for compact binaries individual terms of PN expansions of various quantities are generically divergent (at high enough orders) both in UV and IR. While renormalization allows extraction of meaningful results from those expressions, blanket statement “PN expansion is asymptotic” without additional qualifiers is misleading.

Comment: @A.V.S. Ah, that is the answer to my question then. Thank you so much!!!